# Automatically restart python and new tkinter window

Tags: python, bash, tkinter, kill, restart

Hello I hate ending up here but this one i can't solve by myself.

I've got a python script running using tkinter for UI. It is connected to a bluetooth device and to a wifi plug. The BT gives temp and humidity, the plug turns on air extraction once a certain temp/humidity value is reached. Unfortunately sometimes the BT device gives a NoneType value or the wifi plug cannot be reached. Therefore the script crashes. I've set up a bash script that automatically restarts the python one, but that doesn't seem to update the tkinter window and get it back running! How can I achieve that? Thank you!

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import datetime
import pyHS100
from pyHS100 import SmartPlug
from beewi_smartclim import BeewiSmartClimPoller
import datetime as dt
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

plug_temp = SmartPlug('192.168.0.21')

result = time.strftime("%I:%M")

env_exp = []

window = Tk()

window.title('green room')

lab_text = Label(window, width = 10)
lab_text.grid(column=0, row=0)
lab = Label(window, width = 10)
lab.grid(column=0, row=1)

lab_h_text = Label(window, width = 10)
lab_h_text.grid(column=1, row=0)
lab_h = Label(window, width = 10)
lab_h.grid(column=1, row=1)

lab_t_text = Label(window, width = 10)
lab_t_text.grid(column=2, row=0)
lab_t = Label(window, width = 10)
lab_t.grid(column=2, row=1)

img_on = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('/home/pi/on.png'))
img_off = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('/home/pi/off.png'))

lab_plug_text = Label(window, width = 10)
lab_plug_text.grid(column=3, row=0)
lab_plug = Label(window, width = 50)
lab_plug.grid(column=3, row=1)



def UI():
    b = BeewiSmartClimPoller("F0:C7:7F:85:B4:79")
    time_day = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    temp_c = b.get_temperature()
    humidity = b.get_humidity()
    b.update_sensor()
    env = [temp_c, humidity, time_day]
    env_exp.append(env)
    df = pd.DataFrame(env_exp)
    df.to_csv ('/home/pi/env_export.csv', index = False, header=['Temp', 'H', 'Time'])
    temp = (temp_c,'°C')
    hum = (humidity,'%')
    if temp_c > 25 or humidity > 48:
        plug_temp.turn_on()

    else:
        plug_temp.turn_off()

    lab_text.config(text = 'Time')
    lab.config(text = time_day)
    lab_h_text.config(text = 'Humidity')
    lab_h.config(text = hum)
    lab_t_text.config(text = 'Temperature')
    lab_t.config(text = temp)
    lab_plug_text.config(text = 'Status')
    if plug_temp.state == 'ON':
        lab_plug.config(image = img_on)  
    else:
        lab_plug.config(image = img_off)

    window.after(120000, UI)

UI()
window.mainloop()
```

and the bash code :

```
until python3 flowerbeewi.py; do
 echo "Crashed with exit code $?/ restarting..." >&2
 sleep 3
done
```

Comment: You should fix the Python script instead, by using try/catch and dealing with the exception, e.g. just 'pass' when you get None.

Comment: ok will give it a go thanks

Comment: Got it working and learned something, thanks ypnos!

Comment: Great to hear! Thank you for the feedback.